# Is there an ecommerce framework for javascript

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, product

Lets say for example the front-end aspect of the products listing page, very similar to how the major store brands like target.com, kmart.com, etc implement it.  Is there an ecommerce Javascript framework for that?

Comment: I assume you know this, but there are many ecommerce CMS's (Magento, Shopify, PrestaShop, Zen-Cart, OSCommerce) and ecommerce plug-ins for Wordpress, Joomla, and Drupal.

Comment: Clearly u missed the point of my question.  I wanted to know is there any JAVASCRIPT based ecommerce framework to handle the front-end side of things.

Comment: Please find a reference architecture for [ecommerce using javascript](https://github.com/enghwa/MultiRegion-Modern-Architecture)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

ecommerce requires security because people are constantly trying to steal. Security is the job of the server, not the client. Javascript is a client side language. If you find an app, I wouldn't use it because it, by definition, is insecure. Besides that, javascript has different requirements depending on the version of the browser.

Comment: I see, so there isn't any front-end based ecommerce framework?

Comment: if there is, I wouldn't use it. Too insecure.

Comment: Wrong. NodeJS is a great server plateform in Javascript, with performances largely better than PHP which be used by every ecommerces tools for now. And with frameworks like Meteor or Express, with strong databases, we have the perfect tools to do this.

Comment: It was answered in early 2011 and the large adoption of NodeJS was not that large back then. Many things changed since then and Javascript is not just a "client side language" any more.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out:

http://simplecartjs.org/

These seems to have a good following.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I could see coming close to a JavaScript ecommerce framework is one written with [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), but I don't see anything out there right now available.